# Android shows missed calls even after open

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

My phone shows the missed calls on the app icon even after I check and delete them from log. I did restart / battery off several times but it still hanging there!! Phone Samsung Galaxy S Duos Android Version 4.0.4

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Are you saying about seeing notifications on notification area and pushing clear button? Did you try just to click on the notification and then on back key and to do it repeatedly until all notifications disappear?

Answer (score 1):

go to settings > application> all > badge provider> clear data & clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem on my android phone but tried a solution from one of the android forums which says

Go to settings>>Applications manager>>all applications (on the top) locate the badge provider app, once in there clear data and restart your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the icon of the app from the home launcher then put it back then restart your phone